# How could Akira turn like that in the end of Akira Movie?

Tags: akira

At the end of [Akira The movie](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/akira),

> we could see that Akira was dead long time ago, based on below images, we could see a tube that contain Human organs such as brain, nerves, and other probably that was Akira's Organ.

Went [Takashi](http://akira.wikia.com/wiki/Takashi_(anime)) stood up,

> all of that tube were broken, and out of nowhere, Akira was back alive. 
>  
>  [image: Possibly Akira's nerves]
>  
>  [image]
>  
>  [image]

Why all of sudden [Akira](https://www.anime-planet.com/characters/akira)

> went back alive ?

Comment: The anime deviates and condenses much of the manga it's adapted from. Without spoiling much, the manga Akira (and No. 19) has much more presence than in the anime, which more or less adapts the beginning and end of the series. I recommending checking out the source material for a more of an in-depth experience.